# JQuery Validation Plugin - validate field if option selected

Tags: jquery, validation

I am referring to the following plugin [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

I essentially have a select input

```
<select class="form-control" id="taskSelect" name="taskSelect" >
    <option value="" name="task" id="task">Select One</option>
    <option value="1" name="task">1</option>
    <option value="2" name="task">2</option>
</select>
```

Now this input is required.  Depending on what is selected, a type of sub form appears.  What I am trying to do is validation on whatever subform is displayed.  So if I choose option 1, I dont need to validate option 2's fields.  I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f4fabnz/) to demonstrate.

How would I validate the additional inputs for the selected options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the validation rules like so (minimum markup for clarity):

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <select id="Controller" name="Controller">
        <option value="1">Make Controller 1 Required</option>
        <option value="2">Make Controller 2 Required</option>
    </select>
    <input name="Controlled_1" />
    <input name="Controlled_2" />
</form>
```

Make sure that all of the controlled input fields that need validation have a "name" attribute, because that's what goes into the rules object as the key. I left the id on the controlling select element so that you can easily target it with the required functions used by the controlled input fields.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        Controller: {
             required: true
        },
        Controlled_1: {
            required: function() {
                return $('#Controller').val() == 1
            }
        },
        Controlled_2: {
            required: function() {
                return $('#Controller').val() == 2
            }
       }
    },
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TessaLiliana/mjsdonew/) I forked from yours with the working version.